# Run a exe file through R

Tags: r

I have a .exe file, and want to run it in R!
After running that exe file, a output text file will be created inside of that 
I do not know how to do that?

Thanks all,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following line, just replacing mystring with the path of the .exe file, and cmd as the type (type = "cmd") meaning you are running it from command line

```
system( shQuote( "mystring" , type = c("cmd","sh") ) , ... )
```

Comment: No problem, glad to hear that

Comment: How can I interact with that .exe file? I got one exe that my company uses for access their data... and I need to pass some parameters and features.